# What does Enhanced Capacity in Microsoft Fabric mean?

Tags: microsoft-fabric

I'm trying to set up a Microsoft Fabric workspace by following below steps:

1. Create 'Microsoft Fabric (preview)' instance from Azure Portal
2. Create a new Workspace from 'app.fabric.microsoft.com' with below options:

- License Mode: Fabric Capacity
- Default Storage Format: Small dataset Storage Format
- Capacity: Azure resource created in step1

After environment setup, I'm getting below error while creating Fabric resources:

[image]

'Learn More' and 'Buy Now' links from the popup is redirecting to the Azure portal to create Fabric resource, which I have already created in Step 1. Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Check to make sure your 'Microsoft Fabric (preview)' instance is created in a supported region (not sure why Azure lets you create the capacity in an unsupported region, but it does).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/fabric/admin/region-availability

TL;DR: My tenant is not in a supported region (Central US) so I had a heck of a time getting the Trial license activated, but once activated I still couldn't create any Fabric resources. I then created a 'Microsoft Fabric (preview)' instance in a supported region (South Central US) and I am now able to create Fabric resources for the Data Warehouse and Real-Time Analytics experiences, although I still cannot see the Data Science or Data Engineering experiences anywhere so I'm not sure what is going on with that. Perhaps this is also related to my tenant being in an unsupported region (annoying, but it is a "preview," after all).

Comment: Although I don't see Data Science or Data Engineering experiences in the UI, I can create resources like Lakehouses (which should be under the Data Engineering experience) from the Real-Time Analytics experience, so the missing UI elements appear to be a "preview" bug.